# Give another class access to specific methods

Tags: c++, templates, callback, game-engine

I am working on game engine as a project during the summer. Every scriptable component should have access to some methods in the scene which they are in. To make this possible i pass lambdas from the scene that calls the respective methods to the scriptable where they are implicitly converted to std::function types.

Scene.h:

```
class Scene
{
private:
    unsigned int _currentId;
    std::vector<System*> _systems;

    //SCRIPTABLE NEEDS THE BELOW METHODS THESE EXCLUSIVELY:

    bool exists(unsigned id);
    void destroy(unsigned int);
    void addComponent(Component*, unsigned int);
    template<typename T> T& getComponent(unsigned int);
    template<typename T> bool hasComponent(unsigned int);
    template<typename T> void removeComponent(unsigned int);

protected:
    unsigned int instantiate(std::vector<Component*>);

public:
    Scene(ChangeSceneCallback);
    ~Scene();
    void initiate();
    void update(long dt);
};

template<typename T>
inline T & Scene::getComponent(unsigned int id)
{
    for (System* system : _systems) {
        if (system->corresponds(T)) {
            return static_cast<T*>(system->getComponent(entityId));
        }
    }
}

template<typename T>
inline bool Scene::hasComponent(unsigned int id)
{
    for (System* system : _systems) {
        if (system->corresponds(T)) {
            return system->contains(id);
        }
    }
}

template<typename T>
inline void Scene::removeComponent(unsigned int id)
{
    for (System* system : _systems) {
        if (system->corresponds(T)) {
            return system->destroy(id);
        }
    }
}
```

The callback method works for the non-template functions i need access to, but not the templated ones, so it's out of the question.

Scriptable:

```
typedef std::function<void(int)>                                    ChangeSceneCallback;
typedef std::function<int(std::vector<Component*>)>                 InstantiateCallback;
typedef std::function<void(int)>                                    DestroyCallback;
typedef std::function<bool(int)>                                    ExistCallback;
typedef std::function<void(Component*, unsigned int)>               AddComponentCallback;


class Scriptable: public Component
{
protected:
    ChangeSceneCallback changeScene;
    InstantiateCallback instantiate;
    DestroyCallback destroy;
    ExistCallback exists;
public:
    ~Scriptable();
    Scriptable();
    void assignCallbacks(ChangeSceneCallback, InstantiateCallback etc ...);

    virtual void init() = 0;
    virtual void update() = 0;
};
```

Scriptable can't have access to public methods in scene because this would give the user / developer access to them (Scriptable is a base class for the behaviour of the game). That is why i need to come up with something that gives scriptable limited access to scene.

Any thoughts?

Comment: There is no pointer to template function. It would require runtime code compilation.

Comment: The question makes no sense. As long as template parameter is not fixed (specialized), template is a template. It is not a type, it is not a function. You can define a template typedef (using C++11 features), but this still won't let you use it as a type without specifying the template parameter.

Comment: Do you mind explaining what `system->corresponds(T)` is supposed to mean?

Comment: @Ant Okay, i recently started using templates so i'm not that familiar with them yet. But i think i understand now. Are you saying that you can't do a callback to a template function? Or are you saying that you can't do it the way im trying to do it.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot if the template parameter "matches" the system, which might be a better term. Corresponds is overriden by each system. In the transformsystem for example it tries to cast the template parameter to a transform.

Comment: Whereas `using` is more readable than `typedef` in general, `using` is required for template: `template<typename T> using GetComponentCallback = std::function<T&(unsigned int)>;`. But that still requires to use something like `GetComponentCallback<MyComponent>` for `std::function<MyComponent&(unsigned int)>`

Comment: @ojoj kolol: "Callback" is a rather wide concept in C++ these days. It depends on what you mean by "callback". If you want your callback target to be stored, say, in a `std::function` then you'll have to specialize the target template first, i.e. specify concrete arguments for all template parameters (after which it will not longer be a template).

Comment: @AnT Well, i just want to access those functions they way i would if i had scene stored as a reference in scriptable. But preferably in a way so that i can specify / isolate which functions / methods in scene that scriptable has access too.

Comment: I edited my question with regards to the comments.

Comment: @ojojkolol I rolled it back to when the code was there. Don't delete your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have a type erased "template callback". You have to choose between the template or the type erasure. Let me explain.

This is what a "template callback" look like. This is in fact a generic lambda:

```
auto print_callback = [](auto var) {
    std::cout << var << std::endl;
}

print_callback(4) ;      // prints "4"
print_callback(4.5);     // prints "4.5"
print_callback("hello"); // prints "hello"
```

It seems good but notice that you can't do that with `std::function`, since you have to predefine the signature.

```
std::function<void(int)> func_print_callback = print_callback;

func_print_callback(5); // Yay! Prints "5"
func_print_callback("hello"); // error
```

The thing is, you might think the limitation is only because `std::function` need a specific signature to work with, but the limitation is much deeper than that.

The thing is, the is no *template function*. They don't exists. *Function template* on the other hand, do exist. Why I emphasize so much on the order of my words is because the name of this thing says it all: it is not a *function*, it a *template* that is used to make functions.

Here's a simple example:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T t) {
    std::cout << t << std::endl;
}
```

This function is not compiled. Because it's not a function. No function `foo` will exist until the hole `T` has been filled.

> How do you fill the hole named `T` supposed to be a type?

By filling it with a type of course!

```
foo(5.4); // the hole T is `double`
```

When the compiler sees this, it knows you need a function named `foo` that takes a double as parameter. There is no function named `foo` that takes a `double`. But we gave the compiler a tool to create one: the template!

So the compiler will generate this function:

```
void foo_double(double t) {
    std::cout << t std::endl;
}
```

The word here is this: *generate*. The compiler need to create the function in order to exist. The compiler generate code for you.

When the function is generated and compiled, `T` do not exist anymore. A template parameter is a compile-time entity, and only the compiler knows about them.

---

Now, I'll explain to you why there is no such thing as a template callback.

Type erased container such as `std::function` are implemented with pointer to function. I'll use type aliases to ease the syntax a bit. It works like this:

```
// A function
void foo(int) {}

// The type of the pointer to function
using func_ptr = void(*)(int);

// A pointer to foo
func_ptr ptr = &foo;
```

The pointer to the function foo has a value that points to the location of `foo` in the memory.

Now imagine we have a way to have template function pointer. We would have to point to a function that does not exist yet. It has no memory location, so it cannot make sense. And through the pointer, when invoked as a function, you'd have to generate the function code.

Since a pointer to function can point to any function, even functions that aren't known to the compiler yet, you'd have to somehow generate the function code and compile it. But the value of the pointer, to which function our pointer  points to, is defined at runtime! So you'd have to compile code at runtime, for code that you don't know yet, from a value that does not exist, when the compiler don't exist anymore. As you can see, pointer to template function, template `std::function` or virtual template function cannot exist.

---

Now that you have understood the problem, let me propose a solution: drop the callback usage. You should call those functions directly.

You seem to use callback only to be able to call private member functions. This is the wrong way to do it, even if it works. What you need is `friend`, the feature of C++ that allows you to access private members.

```
class Scene {
    friend Component;

    // ...
};

class Component {
protected:

    // Let `scene` be a reference to your scene

    void addComponent(Component* c, unsigned int id) {
        scene.addComponent(c, id);
    }

    template<typename T>
    T& getComponent(unsigned int id) {
        return scene.getComponent<T>(id);
    }

    template<typename T>
    bool hasComponent(unsigned int id) {
        return scene.hasComponent(id);
    }

    template<typename T>
    void removeComponent(unsigned int id) {
        removeComponent(id);
    }

    // ...
};
```

Since the `Component` class is the only friend to `Scene`, only it can call private member functions. Since all those newly defined functions in `Component` are protected, only class that extends from `Component` can call those. They are invoked like this:

```
class Scriptable : public Component {
    void foo() {
        hasComponent<Bar>(87); // works, call function defined in `Component`
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you! That was quite the answer, i think i need to read it again haha.

Comment: @ojojkolol I suggest you to read more about templates and how they work. They are one of the biggest subject in C++

Comment: I sure will, thanks! I see you are also working on a game engine, how is it going?

Comment: @ojojkolol I would really love to discuss about it, but the comment section is meant exclusively to talk about the answer/question.  I can say however that despite the years of work, and hardly some basic games, it have me a lots and lots of irreplaceable experience. I encourage you to continue your project, learn more about c++ and programming and reward will come.

Comment: Thanks, glad to hear that. I really enjoy game development. I have been using unity for some time but my ideas usually revolve around 2D so unity feels "wrong" (you can make perfectly fine 2D games in unity of course, but working in a 3D environment feels wierd). I am learning more and more everyday, it feels like a game engine is a perfect project for learning software design and especially c++.